# Running a python script with inputs from another python script

Tags: python, input

I have lots of python scripts to be run and I want to automate them. All of them accept inputs at certain times (3 in this case). I have tried something like this but since echo does not have an EOF it did not work:

```
os.system("echo 4 | echo 5 | echo 6 | python script.py")
```

I cannot change the content of script.py and it does not accept arguments to it.

How can I automatically input using a line(s) of python code? Thanks.

Comment: Your shell code simply inputs `6` into the Python script. Piping input to `echo` makes no sense as it ignores its standard input. Probably you mean `printf '%s\n' 4 5 6 | python script.py`. A much better solution is usually to `import script` and run it within your existing script, instead of as a subprocess (though there are scenarios where you do want two processes, such as when you need to be able to interrupt or kill the subprocess from the parent).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

> Pexpect is a pure Python module for spawning child applications;
> controlling them; and responding to expected patterns in their output.
> Pexpect works like Don Libes’ Expect. Pexpect allows your script to
> spawn a child application and control it as if a human were typing
> commands.